# How is the entire $SO(2)$ group the standard rotation matrix?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

In a book I am using, the following is presented,

> $$\mathcal{R}(\phi) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos (\phi ) &\sin (\phi ) \\ -\sin (\phi ) &\cos (\phi )\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> The group's name is $\textrm{SO}(2)$, if the angle $\phi$ varies continuously from $0$ to $2\pi$; $\textrm{SO}(2)$ has infinitely many elements and is compact.

From my understanding, $\textrm{SO}(2)$ is the group of orthogonal matrices each of whose determinants are $+1$. I can definitely see how the rotation matrix forms a subgroup, but I don't see how equality (rotation matrix = $\textrm{SO}(2)$) can be shown (especially so easily as to sweep it under the rug so quickly in this book).

Could you tell me how this can be shown?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order for a matrix to be in SO(2), it has to be (a) orthogonal, and (b) have determinant $1$.

For $(a)$ we need in particular that each row is a unit vector. Every unit vector has the form $(\cos \theta, \sin\theta)$ for some $\theta$, so our matrix necessarily has the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \cos \phi & \sin \phi \end{pmatrix} $$

In addition the rows must be perpendicular to each other. Our two unit vectors are perpendicular if and only if $\phi = \theta\pm\frac\pi 2$, up to irrelevant multiples of $2\pi$. By some basic trigonometric identities, this means that the possibilites are now

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix} \quad\text{ and }\quad \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta \end{pmatrix} $$

The first of these always has determinant $1$, so it is in SO(2). The second has determinant $-1$, so it is not in SO(2) (but it is in O(2)).

---

Things become more complex in higher dimensions. A general form for a member of SO(3) would be
$$ \begin{align} &P^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta &0\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} P\\[1ex] \text{where }& P = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0 & \cos\phi & \sin\phi \\ 0 & -\sin\phi & \cos\phi \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\psi & \sin\psi &0\\-\sin\psi&\cos\psi&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} \end{align} $$
(which you can write out if you want, but it will be horrible), and an element of SO(4) will in general be composed of *two* independent rotations about different axes:
$$ P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta&\sin\theta&0&0\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0&0\\
0&0&\cos\phi & \sin\phi \\ 0&0&-\sin\phi&\cos\phi \end{pmatrix} P $$
where $P$ is some orthogonal basis change that I don't even want to try to separate out into components.

The proofs for these higher-dimensional cases are correspondingly more involved.

Comment: Wow this is perfect. It is $1000x$ easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: Wait what about the more general $\textrm{SO}(n)$ where $n\geq 3$. Would those be rotation matrices in those respective dimensions?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan Yes (if I remember correctly). The special orthogonal groups, $SO(n)$, define a transitive action on the corresponding $n-1$-sphere.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan: I've added some comments about higher dimensions.