# Properties of $O_2$ and $SO_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working on this sheet about the groups $O_2$ and $SO_2$ and I'm having some problems.

*Let $R_\theta$ be the matrix \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\!\!-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\;\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}Show that $SO_2 = \{R_\theta, \theta\in lR\}$. Determine the left (or right) cosets of $SO_2$ in $O_2$ and conclude that if $A\in O_2$ then $A=R_\theta$ or $A=F_\theta=R_\theta F$, where F is the matrix \begin{pmatrix}1&\!\!0\\0&\;-1\end{pmatrix}*

It is easy to prove that any element of $\{R_\theta, \theta\in \Bbb R\} $ is in $SO_2$. Then, any matrix of $SO_2$ satisfies $a^2 + b^2 = 1, ac+bd=0, ad-bc=1, c^2+d^2=1$. Now I don't know how to continue... 
As far as the left cosets are concerned, I know that if $A\in O_2$ then $det(A) = 1$ or $det(A) = -1$. Now let $O\in O_2$ be arbitrary. If $det(O)=1$, then $O\in SO_2$ and $OSO_2 = SO_2O = SO_2$. If $det(O)=-1$, then $OSO_2=...$
Many thanks!

Comment: If $det(O)=-1$, then $det(OF)= det(FO)=1$, hence $OF,FO\in SO_2$, so $O\in F\cdot SO_2, SO_2\cdot F$ (note that $F^{-1}= F$). Therefore you have two cosets of $SO_2$ in $O_2$: $SO_2$ and $F\cdot SO_2$.

Comment: I have a dumb question about notation here:  What do you mean by $\theta \in lR$?  Does this mean $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @MarkFischler, yes, I just didn't know how to write it ahah I've already corrected it.

Comment: For the first question, note that $a^2+b^2=1$ implies that $a=\cos\theta$, $b=\sin\theta$, for some $\theta$. $c^2+d^2=1$ implies $c=\sin\phi$, $d=\cos\phi$, for some $\phi$. Now $0=ac+bd= \cos\theta\sin\phi+\sin\theta\cos\phi= \sin(\theta+\phi)$ implies $\theta+\phi=k\pi$, and $1=ad-bc= \cos\theta\cos\phi-\sin\theta\sin\phi= \cos(\theta+\phi)$ implies $\theta+\phi= 2k\pi$. So, $c=\sin\phi=\sin(2k\pi-\theta)=-\sin\theta$ and $d=\cos\phi= \cos(2k\pi-\theta)= \cos\theta$. Therefore, every $A\in SO_2$ is equal to some $R_\theta$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the entire $SO(2)$ group the standard rotation matrix?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139990/how-is-the-entire-so2-group-the-standard-rotation-matrix)